# using is(':last') to check the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of input elements. I want to bind a `keyup` event handler to them, so that whenever user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, he goes to the next field. But if the input is the last input, then I want to fire the click event of a button, so that user goes to another level. My code is like this:

```
$('.loginBody input:visible').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(this).is(':last')) {
            $('#next').click();
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest('input').focus();
        }
    }
});
```

However, seems that `is(':last')` doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: `$(this)` within the keyup handler only refers to the input where the event occurred.

Comment: since `this` is an `input` what do you expect from `$(this).closest('input')` ? It should return nothing, since inputs can not be nested.. Please post you form's html.

Comment: What does *However, seems that `is(':last')` doesn't work* mean exactly? What does it do? What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:last` returns the last element of a *collection*, and `$(this)` is only a single element collection.

Try using the `:last-child` selector instead, which will check whether your `<input>` is really the last one in that group.

Alternatively, if your fields aren't all in the same parent, reverse the sense of your test:

```
if ($('input').filter(':last').is(this)) {
    // this is the last input
}
```

NB: using `.filter(':last')` rather than `input:last` per recommendations at http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Comment: @Felix Indeed - I'm not sure why the JQuery docs suggest the `.filter()` method.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:** You could create two different bindings:

```
$('.loginBody input:last').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
             $("#result").html("last one");
        }
    });

$('.loginBody input').not(":last").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
             $("#result").html("not last one");
        }
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6gYXk/1/

Answer (score 1):

have you tried **is(':last-child')** pseudoclass instead?

:last-child means "if this element is the last child of its parent". Note that only element nodes (HTML tags) count, these pseudo-classes ignore text nodes.

**edit:**
also to focus closest sibling element use:

```
 $(e.target).next('input').focus();
```

so full code can be:

```
$('.loginBody input:visible').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
            $('#next').click();
        } else {
             $(e.target).next('input').focus();
        }
    }
});
```

i've prepared an example at: http://jsfiddle.net/HhvUF/

Answer (score 0):

The nicest solution might well be to use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) to see if there are any subsequent sibling elements:

```
if ($(this).nextAll().length) {
    $(this).closest('input').focus();
} else {
    $('#next').click();
}
```

NB that I have turned the `if` around to make it easier to read.

If you need to check only for `input` elements, you can supply a selector:

```
if ($(this).nextAll('input').length) {
```